# Как повысить ограничение на размер JSON в 4mb?

Tags: json, node.js

Когда размер JSON строки начинает превышать 4mb, 
происходит ошибка при вызове JSON.parse

```
Exception while invoking method 'renderPDF' SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

1. Можно ли избежать её повысив лимит, либо следует использовать другие форматы передачи данных где нет ограничений (какие?)?
2. Почему установлен такой лимит в 4mb? К чему может привести повышение этого лимита до 150 mb?

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас просто json не поломан?

Comment: Не должен. Если PDF файл получается меньше 4mb всё ок парситься.
И я тут прочитал про ограничения 

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.6.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/json_parserlimits.html

Comment: Гляньте тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153996/is-there-a-limit-on-the-size-of-a-string-in-json-with-node-js Просто у меня обычно нет проблем с размером больше 4mb, может быть дело именно в node.js.

Comment: Я просто проверил у себя - 25mb скормил без ошибок.

Comment: Тут дело в синтаксе `JSON`, а не размер. Проверьте его в [онлайн валидаторе](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator).

Comment: @mix Ну вот я тоже отписал выше, что дело в самом JSON.

Comment: @manking Какое отношение ссылка на ограничения некого постороннего продукта имеет к nodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит повышать ограничение на размер JSON, которое может переварить какой-то конкретный парсер, особенно до таких дурных цифр, как 150 мегабайт.

Мы когда-то столкнулись с тем же самым ограничением - тоже передавали pdf-файлы между системами, только у нас не нода была.

Мы пришли к следующему техническому решению: файл заливался в облако, в JSON передавалось имя файла.

Вам также рекомендую посмотреть в эту сторону.